# Why using datetime.striptime() to convert date for matplotlib not shows the whole date

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, plot

**Update:**

add codes as below fix the issues

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
fig.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y/%m/%d'))
fig.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
'''this for minor ticks'''
fig.gca().xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y/%m/%d'))
fig.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(mdates.MONDAY))
'''disabled major and minor overlapping'''
fig.gca().xaxis.remove_overlapping_locs = False
```

or:
    `plt.xticks(days, [i.date() for i in days])`

[image]

========================================================================

I am doing the exercrise follow by the book, when i use`datetime.strptime()`to convert the date from `.csv` file in matlibplot, it not shows the whole date on x axis
for example, the convert date in list is **[2014-07-01,2014-07-02,...,2014-07-31]** totally 32 in list.

but finally when i plot it in matpltlib it only shows **[2014-07-01,2014-07-05,2014-07-09,2014-07-13]** on x axis
[image]
why it not shows the whole date? and can i modify it?

here's the code:

```
import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime


filename='sitka_weather_07-2014.csv'
with open(filename,'r') as f,open('xx.csv','w') as w:
    content=csv.reader(f,delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
    '''shift to title'''
    header=next(content)
    days,temps=[],[]
    for value in content:
        '''value[0] for the Date'''
        a=datetime.strptime(value[0],'%Y/%m/%d')
        days.append(a)
        '''value[1] for Temp'''
        b=int(value[1])
        temps.append(b)
    print(len(days))
   #>> 31 #here is 32 days in list  



fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
font={'weight':'normal',
      'color':'cyan',
      'fontsize':24,
       }
plt.title('Weather',fontdict=font)
plt.xlabel('Date',fontdict=font)
plt.ylabel('Temperature',fontdict=font)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
for x,y in zip(days,temps):
    plt.text(x,y+0.1,y,ha='center',va='bottom',fontsize=8,color='red')
plt.plot(days,temps,marker='o',mfc='red',mec='None')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Similar to why it doesn't show each and every number on the y axis... it will show as many ticks as are useful. You can use a `DayLocator` to show every day, or an `HourLocator` to show every hour etc.

Comment: ```fig.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y/%m/%d'))```and
```fig.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())``` are really useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally `matplotlib` do not show all labels, if there is a lof them, as it would look cluttered. If you want to show all dates nonetheless you might add following line:

```
plt.xticks(your_full_list_of_dates)
```

above:

```
plt.show()
```

[xticks](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) might be also used for styling.

Comment: it seemed some wrong when i use```plt.xticks(days)``` to show all of the date, the x axis labels are not date.

Comment: @M_Sea: `datetime.strptime` return `datetime` object - which does beyond date also hold time of day (hour, minute and so on). It assumes midnight (`00:00:00`) if time of day is not given. You need to extract date *itself* to be used as your labels. Just do: `plt.xticks(days, [i.date() for i in days])` where `days` is `list` of `datetime`-type objects.